# IPython Widget Continuous_Update False Run First Time?

Tags: ipywidgets

I've got a Interactive Widget where I've set the Continuous_Update to False (it's generating a large amount of data, so I want it only to do it when releasing the MB). However, I *do* want it to run as soon as the widget is displayed, just the first time. How can I do this?

```
from ipywidgets import interactive,  widgets, HBox, VBox, Layout
import traceback

stereo_song_amp_wav, stereo_song_amp_aac, song_rate, song_duration = make_test_song(time_per_note=1)


def animate_music(start_secs=0, resolution=0.25, duration=5):
    global stereo_song_amp_wav, stereo_song_amp_aac, song_rate, song_duration
    s = stereo_song_amp_aac[round(start_secs*song_rate):round((start_secs + duration)*song_rate),:]
    try:
      display_animation_fast([s], song_rate, view_window_secs=resolution, start_time_offset=start_secs)
    except:
      traceback.print_exc()
    return None

i_obj = interactive(animate_music, start_secs=(0, song_duration, 0.25), resolution=(0.05,1.0,0.05), duration=(0.25, song_duration, 0.25))

output = i_obj.children[-1]

h_layout = Layout(display='flex', flex_flow='row', justify_content='center', width='100%')
v_layout = Layout(display='flex', flex_flow='column',justify_content='center', width='100%')

i_obj.children[0].layout.width = '95%'
controls = VBox([i_obj.children[0], HBox(i_obj.children[1:-1], layout = h_layout)], layout =v_layout)
display(VBox([controls, output], layout = v_layout))
```

Thanks in advance,
Winton

Comment: Hmm, so  it seems that the continuous_update flag is not being used here, its the final display of the VBox that is creating a non interactive widget. So I guess what I need to know is how to create the layout I want, WITHOUT destroying the nice Interactive Object properties that I need.

Comment: Furthermore, upon investigation, it appears that Interactive is built to be a VBox, so there's no way of controlling the layout of its children beyond some simple Dictionary style attributes (eg i_obj.children[0].layout.width = '95%')

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it to do what I wanted - I needed the interactive_output version!

```
from ipywidgets import interactive,  widgets, HBox, VBox, Layout
import traceback

stereo_song_amp_wav, stereo_song_amp_aac, song_rate, song_duration = make_test_song(time_per_note=1)

def animate_music(resolution=0.25, duration=5, start_secs=0):
    global stereo_song_amp_wav, stereo_song_amp_aac, song_rate, song_duration, output
    #if (song_duration - start_secs) < duration:
    #  start_secs = song_duration - duration
    s = stereo_song_amp_aac[round(start_secs*song_rate):round((start_secs + duration)*song_rate),:]
    try:
      display_animation_fast([s], song_rate, view_window_secs=resolution, start_time_offset=start_secs, autoplay=True)
    except:
      traceback.print_exc()
    return None

snippet_length = 5.0
resolution = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0.05, max=1.0, step=0.05, value=0.25, description='Resolution:', continuous_update=False)
duration = widgets.FloatSlider(min=1.0, max=song_duration, step=0.25, value=snippet_length, description='Clip Length:', continuous_update=False)
start_secs = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0.0, max=song_duration-snippet_length, step=0.25, value=0.0, description='Seek:', continuous_update=False)

def update_start_secs(*args):
    start_secs.max = song_duration - duration.value
duration.observe(update_start_secs, 'value')

start_secs.layout.width="80%"
h_layout = Layout(display='flex', flex_flow='row', justify_content='center', width='100%')
v_layout = Layout(display='flex', flex_flow='column', justify_content='center', width='100%')

ui = VBox([ HBox([resolution, duration], layout = h_layout), HBox([start_secs], layout = h_layout)], layout =v_layout)
out = widgets.interactive_output(animate_music, {'resolution': resolution, 'duration': duration, 'start_secs': start_secs})

display(ui, out)
```